# Any alternatives to createScriptProcessor to get live raw audio data?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Firefox seems to have a buggy implementation of this audio node ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688994/is-this-a-bug-in-firefox-or-is-chrome-proactively-fixing-something-ive-done-wro)) so, as I suspect bugs in deprecated features are unlikely to get fixed, I'm looking for another solution.

Mozilla's website says `createScriptProcessor` is slated to be replaced by audio workers "soon" but work on that doesn't even seem to have begun yet.

All the libs I've looked at seem to use `createScriptProcessor`. You can get at time domain data from within Analyzer Nodes so that's my next lead but that also seems pretty kludged so I thought I'd ask here in case I've overlooked a better way. Thanks!